# how to integrate qt libraries in eclipse c?

Tags: eclipse, qt, qtgui

I am currently working on a project which uses opencv in eclipse. There was another project given to me which uses qt gui instead, I was wondering if there is a way to include qt libraries in eclipse, e.g. `QGraphicsObject`? I hope the question is not vague. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's just a C++ project you include the Qt libraries like you would any other library, nothing overly special required except you need to make sure your build process calls `qmake` to generate the `moc` files for anything that uses `QObject`.